# Not reading special characters in string literals in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following input txt file:
"Hamlet \r William Shakespeare"
"Romeo and Juliet \r William Shakespeare"
"For the whom the bell tolls \r Earnest Hemingway"

I load it into an array and when I output it I get:

Hamlet \r William Shakespeare.

Why is it not reading the carriage return character?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you output?? How do you store?

Comment: Adding code to your question may be helpful. Please review - [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `\r` in a file, it won't be read as the character `\r` (special return character), it will be read as 2 separate characters `\` and `r`.

You can fix this by replacing the string "\r" with the special charater `\r`.

```
content = content.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\r", with: "\r")
```

Comment: Thanks this worked!  Been driving me crazy for the past couple of days.